# how to display a 3-4-3 flexbox table?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to get my content to display like this
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoLIw.png)

But mine shows up like this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LT7m2.png)

How do I make it so one row has 3 columns, the second one has 4 and the last has 3? with flexbox? Thank you

```
.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: white;
    align-items:baseline;
    width: 60em;
    margin: auto;
    padding: .5em;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.flex-container div {

    flex: 1 0 30%;
    margin: .5em 0;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    font-size: 1em;
    border: 0.1em solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    justify-content: space-between;
    
}
```

Comment: 3-4-3 is not a table.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by placing the cells into rows which themselves are stacked using `flex-direction: column`.

The styling is crude, but try something like this:

```css
.outer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.cell {
    margin: 1.0em;
    padding: 1.0em;
    border: 1px solid black;
    flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Cell 1</div>
        <div class="cell">Cell 2</div>
        <div class="cell">Cell 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Cell 3</div>
        <div class="cell">Cell 4</div>
        <div class="cell">Cell 5</div>
        <div class="cell">Cell 6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell">Cell 7</div>
        <div class="cell">Cell 8</div>
        <div class="cell">Cell 9</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @jon-vee If this solved your problem, please consider marking this answer as accepted.